# Kubuntu, doesn't suceed to open whatsapp links

Tags: chrome, kubuntu

Kubuntu cannot open whatsapp links, but it can open a web whatsapp.
On Ubuntu such operation works smoothly.

> Error message: Error - KIO Client: Could not find any application or handler for whatapp：//send/?phone=919767292808&text&app_absent=0`

#### Screenshot for example:

[image: Screenshot for example:]

My expectations are to open a web.whatsapp.com, with an open message to a shown phone number.

references: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=171427

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us a bit more detail. First, what are you trying to open? What do you expect to happen and what is actually happening? What is that link supposed to do? What is a "web whatsapp"? What whatsapp client are you using? There is no native Linux app for whatsapp as far as I know, so what are you using?

Comment: @terdon. I've added the expectations. Regarding, what is whatsap web, you can see it here: https://web.whatsapp.com/.